# Standard Way To Do Custom Work Within A Page?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, html, child-theme

First post here, looking forward to using this community more.

I'm trying to figure out the "standard" way or "proper" way of doing custom HTML work within a particular page.

For example, I'm creating a page that has images floated to the left and right of text going down a page. However, I'm finding it difficult to create spacing in the page itself.

Here's a page I'm working on for example:

http://www.simonsayswebsites.com/how-we-get-you-more-customers/

If you look after the "like" button, I have tried multiple things to create spacing underneath the text above the `<hr />`, but no go. I have tried multiple times to create spacing within this page trying all different tags, but I've gotten to the point where now I'm not sure if there is another proper way I should be doing this?

I disabled the visual editor thinking this would fix it, but no go. Perhaps I should use TinyMCE for stuff like this? Or anyone have any recommendations for the right way to do things in editing page content spacing which should be easy with html, but is becoming more complicated here with something not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

- The easiest way is to simply add html/css in the editor (set it to html). Do not use the visual editor afterwards!
- As an alternative you can use [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to add custom html/css to your output
- Add custom [classes to tinymce](http://wesbos.com/custom-wordpress-tinymce-wysiwyg-classes/), [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor/)

### Extra

- [Post snippets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-snippets/)